# ShareX: make a GIF of the second monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, screen-capture

I would like to do a GIF animation displaying fully only my second monitor.

Is it possible with the [ShareX - the Screen Capture Tool](https://getsharex.com/)?

I tried to use the region capture using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> but the region selector captures only specific window or the both screens, but not just the active display...

[image]

Comment: You should get a selection tool if you decide to capture a region. Did you try to drag that region to the size of your second display?

Comment: I didn't achieve to target a single display, it takes the both or just window par window